# Interchanging limits and little-o notation

Tags: limits, asymptotics

If $f(n)=\displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^{\infty} o(1)$ converges for all finite $n,$ is it possible to say $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}f(n)=0$?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $f(n)$ does not seem to be dependent on $n$? Did you mean the upper bound of the sum to be $n$?

Comment: $f(n)=\displaystyle\sum_{l=1}^{\infty}a(n,l),$ in which $a(n,l)=o(1)$ for all $n.$

Comment: $a(n,l)=\frac 1 l$ if $l \leq n$ and $0$ if $l >n$ gives a counter-example.

Comment: For instance $a(n,l)$ could be $\frac{1}{n\cdot l^2}$, but I was wondering if the above hold for all such $a(n,l).$

Comment: But $a(n,l)=1/l$ isn’t $o(1)$?

Answer (score 2):

If $a(n,\,l)=[n\ge l]/n$ in terms of [Iverson brackets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iverson_bracket), then $f(n)=\sum_{l=1}^n1/n=1$.